# Magento Import Products - Invalid image file type

Tags: magento

I'm creating a csv file to import automatically via cron.I have used the code given here( http://www.semtruth.com/importing-images-from-external-url-into-magento/ ) to add images which are present on an external url.

But during import error is fired as "Invalid image file type.".

Can anyone pls help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

Magento only accept 'jpg','jpeg','gif','png' image types. You should check your image file extension before importing.

Comment: I was using jpg only .... meanwhile I have sorted this issue by updating the external image code itself and it's working nicely